# Are the shows Breaking Bad and The Walking Dead in the same universe?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad, the-walking-dead

Rewatching *The Walking Dead*, I noticed a scene where Daryl goes through Merles drugs and in the bag was Walt aka Heisenberg's blue meth.

From my quick google research, pure meth is never blue an inconsistency in *Breaking Bad* which means any meth should be shown as its normal colour outside of the *Breaking Bad* universe.

Out of universe, this is explained that since both shows probably use the same props on the AMC network, however I'm looking for in universe or director/producer comments that give some indication that they could be in the same universe.

[image: blue meth from The Walking Dead]

Comment: Do you know which episode this scene is from?

Comment: I think season 2 episode 2 or 3...

Comment: Its more like a homage to the co-show rather then sharing universe.

Comment: Already been answered, but FYI I saw a VICE documentary on the real life Walter White, and he said meth can be any colour you want, and he has seen blue, pink and purple meth.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[**Did ‘The Walking Dead’ Cook Up a ‘Breaking Bad’ Reference?**](http://artsbeat.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/10/24/did-the-walking-dead-cook-up-a-breaking-bad-reference/)

> [**Robert Kirkman**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Kirkman), a creator of the *“Walking Dead”* comics and a producer of the television series, said that **the inclusion of the blue meth was indeed *"a little Easter egg we were doing for AMC fans"***

(*The Walking Dead* and *Breaking Bad* are both [AMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMC_%28TV_channel%29) shows)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a link that you might like!

[How Breaking Bad and The Walking Dead are connected](https://www.looper.com/146984/how-breaking-bad-and-the-walking-dead-are-connected/)

It shows that AMC has been deliberatly putting signs that both shows are in the same universe, some fans going has far as saying that the blue meth is the cause of the zombie apocalypse.

The biggest proof on my behalf is the red car Walter bought. It is used by Glenn to escape Atlanta in the first season.

Have a nice read!

Edit : I found out another fun connection between the two shows! In the sixth episode of the third season of Breaking Bad, Gale presents Walt his "coffee maker". This same coffee maker can be found in Milton's laboratory in the third season of The Walking Dead.

[image: Coffee is a geek thing I guess.]

Comment: Are you sure that's the same thing and not just some arbitrary lab stuff?

Comment: Well, everything here is speculation. A lot of theories are going on around those two shows. For example, people are saying that the fact Gus walked out of the room after the explosion of half his face his a proof that zombies were coming and that it was the beginning of the meth going bad. The show makers are putting these hints for us to see. Of course, it can be another lab setup, but I like to think that it is the same one. Also, it is for the same use so I think it is fairly reasonable to think it is the same.

Answer (score 4):

Although AMC confirmed that they're the same universe, according the TWD canon they aren’t.

In TWD, the idea of zombies in pop culture doesn't exist, so there aren’t any movies, games, books or TV shows about 'zombies'. However, in Breaking Bad (I'm specifically referencing season 4 episode 2), Skinny Pete and Badger have a full debate about different zombie games including Resident Evil and Call of Duty. They even say "zombie" multiple times, proving that there are zombies in pop culture in the Breaking Bad universe, so canonically TWD and Breaking Bad are not in the same universe.

Answer (score 3):

On the 10th September, 2017 episode of Talking Dead, Hardwick mentioned that viewers claimed to have heard the 'Heisenberg Song' playing in the background of the previous Fear the Walking Dead. He asked for, on air, and received, confirmation from the shows producers, that this was indeed the case, "officially" confirming, as he put it, that the two shows were in the same universe.

Edit to add: [Article from The Independent about this.](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/tv/news/the-walking-dead-breaking-bad-theory-fear-season-8-same-universe-prequel-sequel-a7955031.html)

The episode of the Talking Dead is Season 7 episode 23, which covers episodes 309 & 310 of FTWD.

Answer (score 0):

While there may have been some "Easter eggs" in ***The Walking Dead*** linking it to ***Breaking Bad***, the probable supposition has to be that the two universes are not connected. ***The Walking Dead*** is a fictional representation of a dystopian post apocalyptic Earth meaning that unless the events of ***Breaking Bad*** occurred before the beginning of TWD, then they exist in two very separate universes.

Comment: The events of Breaking Bad DID occur prior to the beginning of TWD. The events of BB began in 2008, while the viral outbreak that kicks off Walking Dead occurs in 2010.